# Coordinate transform between two cameras

Tags: c++, camera, transform, coordinate-systems

I'm working on a system where there are two cameras, A and B. The cameras have differing properties, field of view, focal point etc.

I get some pixel coordinates in the 2d image of the first camera A and I want to transform those into the equivalent coordinates in the 2d image of camera B.

What properties do I need to know to be able to perform this transformation? And how is the transformation done? For simplicity we can assume that both cameras exist in the exact same physical location and point in the same direction but suggestions about how to handle small offsets in x,y,z is also appreciated.

Any suggestions or even a nudge in the right direction is very appropriated. I've tried searching but I barely know what this problem is called.

My program is in C++ if anyone happens to have library that implements this functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: _I get some pixel coordinates in the 2d image of the first camera A_ What about depth? It is impossible to reconstruct 3d coordinates from 2d coordinates without additional info. Assuming you can build the 3d->2d mapping (matrix) from camera configurations, you may apply the inverse for 2d->3d mapping and the matrix of 3d->2d mapping for the 2nd camera. Concerning libraries: [tag:opencv] for image processing or any 3d math library for 3d transformations in general like e.g. [tag:glm].

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix  Is a place to begin to learn about the principles of transforming from one coordinate system to another.

Comment: Thanks ttemple I’ll take a look. Scheff I don’t need 3D coordinates, only 2D. Or is that also not possible? Seems like it should be if you know about the cameras. I have depth for camera A but not B.